# How to add AggregateRatingin in GTM using DOM element Variables?

Tags: schema, google-tag-manager, json-ld

The Product Schema code that i am using as a custom HTML tag for implementing product schema using DOM variables in GTM..

```
<script>
var jsonData = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": {{productName}},
  "image": {{productImg}},
  "url": {{Page URL}},
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": {{avgRating}},
    "reviewCount": {{ratingsCount}},
  }
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'application/ld+json';
  script.text = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  $("head").append(script);
</script>
```

how can i configure the DOM element variable for AggregateRating Variables (avgRating, ratingsCount) in GTM.

here is the Markup

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
        <div class="star-rating">
            <span style="width:100%">
                <strong class="rating">5.00</strong> out of <span>5</span>              based on <span class="rating">1</span> customer rating          </span>
        </div>
        <a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<span class="count">1</span> customer review)</a>    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML markup to your question, because we need to understand where to find it in your markup

Comment: added the HTML markup above(avgrating, avgreviews)..

Comment: i also try through the ID also the class...but then the whole review article showing...but i want the average integer value for those variables. How can i extract the exact average integer value for those..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two variables in GTM

1) Go to `Variables->User-Defined Variables->New->Custom Javascript`

2) Create variable with name `ProductAvgRating` and JS code:

```
function () {
  try {
    return parseFloat(document.querySelector('.woocommerce-product-rating strong.rating').innerText);
  }
  catch(e) {return 0;}
}
```

2) Create variable with name `ProductRatingsCount` and JS code:

```
function () {
  try {
    return parseInt(document.querySelector('.woocommerce-product-rating span.rating').innerText);
  }
  catch(e) {return 0;}
}
```

And then change your html tag like that:

```
<script>
var jsonData = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": {{productName}},
  "image": {{productImg}},
  "url": {{Page URL}},
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": {{ProductAvgRating}},
    "reviewCount": {{ProductRatingsCount}},
  }
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'application/ld+json';
  script.text = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  $("head").append(script);
</script>
```

P.S. You didn't ask about `productName` and `productImg` variables, i guess you already have it

Comment: thank you so much for reply. Hope it will works. And Yes, for productName and productImg used DOM variable CSS element. While debugging, it shows the exact value. That is why i do not mention.

Comment: If my solution is working for you, please accept my answer

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for your reply..Helps me a lot. I am New here. My reputation is not well yet. So i am unable to upvote..